# Hibernate reverse engineering -annotations names in upper case

Tags: hibernate, reverse-engineering, hibernate-mapping

I am generating pojos via hbm2java reverse Engineering. And for annotation names turning ejb3="true".

but my problem is @Table(name="EMPLOYEE") **I want @Table(name="Employee")**. The reverse engineering code is not written by me. We are uing xpand for generating pojos and Ejb3*****.ftl s for annotations.

@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")

public class Employee {

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Cases-sensitive table names make only sense if they are put into backticks. 
You can use a `hibernate.reveng.xml` file to control the reverse engineering process of `hbm2java` (see [Controlling reverse engineering](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html)) of the Hibernate Documentation.

The default implementation does not support case sensitive names so you'll have to provide  your own `org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.MetaDataDialect` where you'll have to implement the `Iterator getTables(String catalog, String schema, String table);` to return case sensitive table names, i.e. table names in backticks.

If you do this you may also have to provide a Custom `org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.ReverseEngineeringStrategy` to generate correct Class names and Identifiers from 'case sensitive' table names.

Comment: Yes you are correct we are using back ticks for the names because of some reserved name issue. But I can not introduce reveng.xml as it would a bit radical in the legacy code. You mean to say that default annotations will always be upper case? To add back ticks i am editing ftl files {pojo.generateJoinColumnsAnnotation(property, cfg).replaceFirst("=\"", "=\"`").replaceAll("\",", "} stuff like that.

Comment: Not sure if the hibernate tools always per default create uppercase table names, that are the ones I've seen until now. There is an undocumented property `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifier` see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5673. I personally would not rely on that. One option I can think of that it may work is to define a mapping between the uppercase table names and the case-sensitive table names within the ftl file(s), but I've never tried that.